# XCode 6 Beta Swift, SpriteKit: Changing Deployment Target

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode6

When I change my deployment target in Xcode 6 Beta from IOS 8 (Compiles, testable on Simulator) to IOS 7.1(Compiles, testable on Simulator) so that I can test it on my device(5s), my code wont compile anymore.

The line in question is:

```
      let distanceToTravel: CGFloat = (2.0*fabsf(location.x - self.playerNode!.position.x))/self.frame.width
```

The compiler error says it can not find the member position.x

When I set distanceToTravel to a fixed value I can test it on my phone,
but the textures wont get loaded.

Has anyone had any similar issues with XCode 6 Beta + swift?

Comment: Which iDevice are you compiling to?

Comment: I am trying to run it on an iPhone 5s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `fabsf` takes `CFloats`. But `location.x` and `self.playerNode!.position.x` are `CGFloats`, not `CFloats`. So all you need do is cast them like so:

```
let distanceToTravel: CGFloat = CGFloat(2.0*fabsf(CFloat(location.x) - CFloat(self.playerNode!.position.x))) / self.frame.width
```

OH and did I mention you need to cast the result?

Comment: I really dont think so. I tried casting and it didnt work.
After casting I got an error related to the overloading of the / operator.

Also fabsf is of type CGFloat and I believe position.x is also of type CGFloat

But I will check this out when I get home. Maybe I was sloppy when casting

Comment: @MarcHPunkt I've tried tried this line of code... And it compiles and runs... Trust me ;), It works. And `fabsf` does take a `CFloat` and returns a `CFloat`. If you don't believe me, just try it.

Comment: I will and report back in bit

Comment: it works it works :) except for the textures, but that seems to be a different problem

Comment: Ya, the important thing is to remember that this is a Beta, other than that. Welcome to Swift.

Comment: @MarcHPunkt Meh, in my opinion, Swift is too strict with casting. Especially since there are 3 different types of floats.

Comment: I had a little bit different problem. I managed to make my expression compile and work using Floats, Integers but the project was compiling for either 32 or 64 bit architecture. The right code was different for different arcs. When I used CGFloat everything worked like I needed it to.